# Gardine vs. Vorhang und Jalousie vs. Rolladen

Tags: meaning, regional

*Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob das hier als zwei verschiedene Fragen gestellt werden sollte, und ob es nicht zu sehr um persönliche Meinungen geht. Wenn dem so ist bitte korrigieren oder löschen.*

Mir ist gerade im Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache das Thema "Sichtschutz" untergekommen: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f08a-b/

Üblicherweise werden im Atlas verschiedene Begriffe für gleiche Dinge genannt (Samstag/Sonnabend, Junge/Knabe, Brötchen/Semmel ...), in diesem Fall beschreiben die Antworten m. E. aber unterschiedliche Dinge. Hier mein Verständnis der unterschiedlichen Begriffe, die mir als Norddeutschem geläufig sind:

- Gardine: besteht aus dünnem, häufig fast transparentem, gemusterten Stoff. Ist nachts bei eingeschalteter Innenbeleuchtung als Sichtschutz ungeeignet, Sonnenlicht wird diffus und nur leicht gedämpft durchgelassen.
- Vorhang: besteht aus schwererem, meist opakem Stoff, meist gleichmäßig einfarbig. Ist als Sonnenschutz tagsüber und Sichtschutz nachts gut geeignet; im Kino und Theater eingesetzt noch etwas "schwerer" als im Wohnzimmer.
- Jalousie: einzelne Lamellen, die an Fäden aufgehängt sind, hoch- und runtergelassen sowie gedreht werden können. Meistens innen angebracht. Dient als Licht- und Sichtschutz.
- Rolladen: einzelne Lamellen, die über Ober- und Unterkante mit der jeweils nächsten Lamelle verbunden sind. Wird in einem Rolladenkasten aufgerollt und kann nur hoch- oder runtergelassen werden. Bietet neben Licht- und Sichtschutz auch eine gewisse Einbruchsicherheit.

Die Google-Images-Suche mit den o. g. Begriffen bestätigt subjektiv meine Einschätzung.

Meine Frage also: Handelt es sich hier um relativ klar voneinander abgegrenzte Begriffe, oder unterscheidet sich die Bedeutung doch regional sehr stark voneinander? Oder liegt es eher daran, dass für die im Atlas genannten Zwecke (Sichtschutz innen, Sichtschutz außen) regional unterschiedliche Gegenstände zum Einsatz kommen, bspw. im Norden eher Gardinen, im Süden eher Vorhänge nach den o. a. Beschreibungen?

**Zur akzeptierten Antwort:** Ich hätte natürlich gerne beide Antworten (Stand 31.5.16) akzeptiert, da sie ähnliches aussagen. Das sind jetzt zwar nur vier Datenpunkte (inkl. mir selbst), aber zusammen mit dem Kommentar von Robert bestätigt sich in etwa das Bild, das auch die Karte im Atlas zeigt: Im Norden und Westen wird zwischen Gardine und Vorhang unterschieden, während im Süden (Bayern, Österreich) nur Vorhang für beide Formen (dünn/durchsichtig und dick/undurchsichtig) verwendet wird.
Also ähnlich wie die Verwendung von *Fuß* für alles unterhalb des Beckens im schwäbischen Raum, während anderswo zwischen den einzelnen Bestandteilen des Beins unterschieden wird.

Comment: Übrigens wird gemäß den aktuellen Regeln das aus _Roll-_ und _Laden_ zusammengesetzte Kompositum _[Rollladen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Rollladen)_ mit drei _l_ geschrieben. Der genannte Artikel im Atlas der Alltagssprache basiert auf einer Umfrage aus den Jahren 2006 und 2007, also gerade noch aus der Übergangszeit.

Comment: Meine Oma würde wahrscheinlich auch noch die Gardine von einer Store unterscheiden, aber ich verwende die Begriffe genauso, habe aber im Westteil des Sprachgebiets schon häufiger _Jalousien_ für Rollladen gehört. (Auch die heute unüblich gewordenen klappbaren Fensterladen sind ja üblicherweise an der Außenwand befestigt.)

Comment: Ich würde die Begriffe genauso wie Du definieren und abgrenzen. Ich bin aus dem Rheinland.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich beantworte die Frage aus der Sicht von Österreich (genauer: Aus dem Osten Österreichs):

### Gardine:

Das Wort ist Bestandteil des passiven Wortschatzes (man versteht was das Wort bedeutet, verwendet es aber nicht). Im Gegensatz zu vielen anderen Wörtern hat man in Österreich aber nicht den Eindruck, dass es ein deutsches Wort ist (»deutsch« ist hier ausdrücklich im geografischen Sinn gemeint, also »zu Deutschland gehörend«). »Gardine« ist einfach nur eine selten benutze Bezeichnung für einen bestimmten Vorhangtypus.

Für »Gardine« gilt auch in Österreich genau die Definition aus der Frage.

### Vorhang:

Das ist in Österreich jedes Stück Stoff, das man **vor** ein Fenster **hängt**, und das ungefähr die Größe des Fensters hat. Farbe, Musterung und vor allen der Grad der Transparenz machen dabei keinen Unterschied. Wenn der Kontext auf nichts anders schließen lässt, ist damit aber eher die durchsichtige Variante gemeint.

Eine für Österreich typische Verwendung, die auf die Transparenz eines Vorhangs abzielt, ist diese:

> Nein, diese Bluse ziehe ich nicht an. Die ist ja ganz durchsichtig! Da könnte ich ja gleich einen Vorhang anziehen.

Aber auch das hört man:

> Geh, Lisa, zieh bitte die Vorhänge zu, es kann ja jeder hereinschauen.

Was natürlich nur bei opaken Vorhängen Sinn macht.

### Jalousie

Ursprünglich ein Sichtschutz der aus horizontalen Lamellen besteht, die an Schnüren befestigt sind, und deren Neigung man durch Ziehen an Schnüren verstellen kann. Die Lamellen sind aus dünnem Blech oder Kunststoff, manchmal auch aus Holz.

Das definierende Element einer Jalousie sind die beweglichen Lamellen und die Schnüre. Zieht man eine Jalousie auf, sammeln sich die Lamellen in einem Stapel am oberen Fensterrand an. Ob Jalousie innen oder außen montiert sind ist egal. Ich persönlich kannte in meiner Jugend (geboren 1965) gar keine Innenjalousien sondern nur Außenjalousien.

### Rollladen

Dieses Wort wird in Österreich recht deutlich als deutsch (wieder im geografischen Sinn, also »zu Deutschland gehörend«) wahrgenommen und kaum aktiv verwendet.
Man versteht darunter sowohl eine Rollo (siehe unten) als auch ein Scherengitter (etwa zum Schutz vor Einbrechern vor einem geschlossenem Geschäftseingang, also ganz ohne Sichtschutz-Funktion).

### Rollo

Das ist ein Sichtschutz, der aus festem, opakem Stoff, oder aus schmalen miteinander verbundenen Brettern (aus Holz, Metall oder Kuststoff) besteht, die beim Aufziehen auf einer Rolle über dem Fenster oder über der Tür aufgerollt werden.

Das definierende Element einer Rollo ist die Rolle, auf der der Sichtschutz aufgerollt werden kann (im Gegensatz zum Stapel bei einer Jalousie).

Comment: Sehr interessant, vor Allem ***die** Rollo*, und dass die Unterscheidung Jalousie/Rollo wie in Bayern getroffen wird. Das scheint nahezulegen, dass beim Atlas viele Österreicher an ein anderes Gerät gedacht haben als viele Deutsche.

Comment: @Jan: Da du den Artikel so hervorhebst, vermute ich, dass dir ein anderer Artikel vertrauter ist. Welcher? Der Rollo oder das Rollo? (Mir kommen beide Möglichkeiten gleich seltsam vor, aber Deutsches Deutsch und Österreichisches Deutsch weichen gerade bei Artikeln häufig voneinander ab.)

Comment: Bei mir ***der** Rollo.*

Comment: für mich (Mecklenburger) wäre es ***das*** *Rollo*, die Unterscheidung zur Jalousie (welche zusammengezogen wird, nicht aufgerollt) existiert wie bei Hubert.

Comment: Abgesehen vom Artikel für *das* Rollo. Ist das im Schwäbischen genauso, alles, was innen vor dem Fenster hängt, ist ein Vorhang, was draußen hängt, ein Laden

Comment: @tofro: In Österreich: Fensterläden sind wie Fenster- oder Türflügel an Angeln montiert und können um die senkrechte Achse, die von diesen Angeln vorgegeben ist, gedreht werden. Es gibt aber zwei wesentliche Unterschiede zwischen einem Laden und einem Flügel: 1. Ein Fensterladen schwenkt nach außen (üblicherweise um ca. 180°), ein Flügel nach innen (meist um nur 90°). 2. Ein Fensterladen ist undurchsichtig (besteht meist aus Holzbrettern), ein Fensterflügel ist durchsichtig (Glas in einem Rahmen).

Answer (score 1):

Explizit war im Atlas nur gefragt nach:

> Sichtschutz vor einem Fenster aus Stoff, den man von innen als Sichtschutz vorzieht [sic!]

(Entsprechend die [Gardine/Vorhang-Karte](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/f4_08a.jpg)), sowie:

> Sichtschutz vor einem Fenster aus Plastik- oder Holzlamellen, die außen heruntergelassen wird [sic!]

(Entsprechend die [Rollladen/Jalousie/Rollo-Karte](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/f4_08b.jpg)).

Dementsprechend wurde explizit *keine* Unterscheidung zwischen der Schwere des Stoffs (Gardine/Vorhang) getroffen, und es wurde *nicht* nach dem gefragt, das du *Jalousie* nennst.

Dass im Atlas gerne einmal gleiche Wörter in verschiedenen Gegenden verschiedenes bedeuten ([Omelett/Pfannkuchen Teil 1](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f01a/), [Pfannkuchen Teil 2](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f03/), [Paprika/Pepperoni](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f06a-b/) uvm.) ist keine Seltenheit, wobei in meiner Beobachtung allerdings die häufigste Bedeutungsgrenze die Schweizer Grenze ist. Teilweise kannten die Umfragenbetreiber noch nicht einmal die Unterschiede wie im Fall *abschlagen.*<sup>[1]</sup>

### Was die Verwendung der Wörter betrifft:

Für einen Stoff (kann auch Plastikstoff sein), den ich mir innen ans Fenster hänge, und den ich nach links und rechts verschieben kann, würde ich ausschließlich **Vorhang** benützen. Egal ob der Stoff schwer oder leicht ist, ob man hindurchschauen kann oder nicht. Falls es sich um senkrecht hängende Lamellen handelt, würde ich es wahrscheinlich **Lamellenvorhang** nennen. *Gardine* existiert in meinem passiven Wortschatz, aber nicht mehr. Da ich keine Unterscheidung zwischen den beiden Varianten treffe, hätte ich unter *Gardine* auch beides verstanden.

Es gibt öfters Fenster an denen zwei Vorhänge angebracht sind: Ein dünner, der das Sonnenlicht dämpfen soll, und ein dicker, der Nachts einen Sichtschutz und in der Früh Dunkelheit garantieren soll.

Eine **Jalousie** kann sowohl aus Lamellen bestehen, aber auch aus Stoff sein; wichtig ist, dass sie senkrecht auf- und abgelassen wird. Sie kann außen oder innen angebracht sein. Bis auf die Feinheit, dass ich auch Stoffjalousien kenne, dürften wir auf einer Wellenlänge sein.

**Rollladen** verwende ich wie du, wobei ich (den) **Rollo** als Kurzform davon aufgefasst hätte. (Der Atlas beschreibt hingegen eine Etymologie aus dem Französischen.) Davon zu unterscheiden sind selbstverständlich **Fensterläden,** die aus einem festen, meist hölzernen Teil bestehen und von außen vor das Fenster geklappt werden.

---

### Was die Verwendung an Fenstern betrifft:

In Bayern ist der Rollladen die Standardausstattung eines Fensters. In Braunschweig war ich überrascht, wie wenig Fenster eigentlich Rollläden haben; die meisten sind überhaupt nicht mit etwas ausgestattet. (Die Wenigen, die etwas zum Verdunkeln von außen haben, sind meist nachträglich mit Rollläden ausgestattet worden.) Außenjalousien sehe ich hier relativ selten an Wohngebäuden. Diese sehr kleine Stichprobe spricht eher dagegen, dass unterschiedliche Gegenstände in Gebrauch sind.

---

[1]: In Deutschland und vermutlich auch Österreich: Beim Fangalesspiel antippen. In der Schweiz: spitalreif (krankenhausreif) schlagen. Die genaue Atlasseite habe ich gerade nicht im Kopf.

Comment: +1 nur deswegen, weil ich das Wort *Fangalesspiel* in deiner Fussnote 3 mal lesen musste, um draufzukommen...